# how to change the text of a row inside a list view on a button click

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

i have a list view which contain Textview and Edittext.
i have a button on same layout. I want that when i click that button , some position as take data on position 3 of the list view is changed by some other text

i have tried this code but its not working

thid

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskstrt, parent, false);

                   if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {

                         holder = new ViewHolder();



                        holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                        holder.textView.setText(values.get(position).toString());
                        holder.editText.setText(arrayList2.get(position).toString());
                        holder.textView.setId(position);
                        holder.editText.setId(position);
                        holder.editText.setEnabled(false);


                   }

                   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{


                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.editText.setId(2);
                        holder.editText.setText("ACCEPT");
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("ERROR:");
                        }
                    }
                });

                   convertView.setTag(holder);
                   return convertView;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly this is how the `getView` should look:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taskstrt, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //..instantiations

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //^don't forget that this up there


    //...listeners and what not here
    return convertView;
}
```

Moreover, i noticed that your button isn't instanatiated as part of the getView, like the other holder views are. As in where is?

```
Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Why isn't it part of the holder class if it is part of the same layout? if the button wasn't instantiated as part of the same view hierarchy or at all, then the button won't respond to anything.